# How to install SSIS on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, connectivity, ssis-2014

I am installing SQL Server 2014, including SSIS, on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

From this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137861(v=sql.120).aspx
ssis uses port 135 which should be opened on the firewall(s).

I Create a domain account to run SSIS
[image]

Install SQL - features can be seen on the picture below
[image]

All services are running fine
see a special ad account to run the ssis services
[image]

Grant the logon as a service and lock pages in memory
[image]

On control panel -> administrative tools-> Computer management
[image]

Add the users and the ssis account to “distributed com users”
[image]

> ```
> On control panel -> Administrative Tools > Component Services
>
> Then go to computer-> my computer -> DCOM Config -> and look for Microsoft
> SQL Server Integration Services 12.0
>
> As you can see on the picture below
> ```

[image]

You right click on Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0

[image]

I have left the Authentication Level as “call”.
[This is more detailed explained if you follow this link.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107736/when-installing-sql-server-2014-ssis-what-are-the-meaning-of-authentication-le)

[image]

[image]

These 3 above have to be set up, I have done, and the results are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Doing all this above, 
When I run SSMS “As Administrator” on the Server itself, then it works fine.

[image]

**AFTER I REBOOTED THE SERVER I CAN CONNECT SO THE MESSAGE BELOW IS FIXED**

> But on the Server itself if I run SSMS as myself, I get the following
>   error message:
>
> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer
>   "sqldw01" failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
>
> By default, only administrators have access to the Integration
>   Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be
>   running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the
>   Integration Services service. See the help topic for information on
>   how to configure access to the service.

I am administrator on the box.

[image]

and when I try to connect from my local machine, then I get the following error:

**I CANNOT CONNECT USING SQL SERVER 2012 OR LOWER, BUT I CAN CONNECT FINE USING SQL SERVER 2014**

[image]

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "sqldw01" failed with the following error:

> "Class not registered". This error can occur when you try to connect
>   to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current
>   version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service
>   configuration file to let the local Integration Services service
>   manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

What am I missing?

The problem that remains solving is
How to connect to SSIS 2014 from a client using SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSIS intallation is working as a charm, the only problem was that we wanted to connect to SSIS 2014 from SSMS 2012.

At the end we agreed to upgrade the developers machines to sql server 2014 developer edition, and migrated the packages to sql 2014, and now everything is working fine.

I will leave the question here as a reference, for the community and for myself, because at the end I had so many problems, and they all have been solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below steps as mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083(v=sql.110).aspx) :

- Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config ->
  MSDTSServer
- Right click on MSDTSServer
- Click properties
- Click on the Security tab
- Select Customize and add the users/groups to the Launch/Activation
  and Access tabs accordingly
- Add the user to the local Distributed COM Users group
- Restart the SSIS service

Also, would suggest you to go through the tip [How to resolve SSIS access denied error in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3086/how-to-resolve-ssis-access-denied-error-in-sql-server-management-studio/) which has helped us as well.

Comment: I believe I went through all that, I even updated the question to reflect it. Unless I missed something, in that case, please point it out, because I haven't noticed.