# When installing SQL Server 2014 SSIS, what are the meaning of "authentication level"?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, installation, ssis-2014

After installing SSIS 2014, it is the time to deal with the permissions.

When dealing with the DCOM Config (control Panel->Administrative Tools-> Component Services), you want to set up the permissions for Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0 as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

You right click on it, and on the first tab, called General, you see the option Authentication Level. The default is Call, but there are other options, as you can see on the picture.

Where is the documentation for this? What does each option really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link on SQL Server 2014 for you to **Grant Permissions to Integration Services Service**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh213130(v=sql.120).aspx

The first step is: Run Dcomcnfg.exe. Dcomcnfg.exe provides a user interface for modifying certain settings in the registry.

The following link for DCOM settings were last reviewed in 2006, but the options look unchanged.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/176799

This describes *Default Authentication Level (Packet Level)* which is the screenshot that you posted.

Other subheadings describe several other facets of the DCOM setup.